# how to match exact string in javascript regex

Tags: javascript, php, regex

My JavaScript regex is

```
/\[DEF\]([^\[\]]+)\[\/DEF\]/g
```

my string is

```
[DEF]sdgsdggsFfg sdgsdg[/DEF]
```

I want to check in my regex that in the middle `[/DEF]` don't come what can I do for it.

When I modify this regex as `/\[DEF\]([^\[\/DEF]]+)\[\/DEF\]/g`
but in the regex it is matching single character eg D, E , or F I want to match it with exact `[/DEF]`

What can I do for it.

Comment: There's been so many answers for that... A simple one: `/\[DEF\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/DEF\]/g`. A more advanced: `/\[DEF]([^[]*(?:\[(?!\/DEF])[^[]*)*)\[\/DEF]/g`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simple RegExp:

```
/\[DEF\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/DEF\]/g
```

For making it case-insensitive (def instaead of DEF)

```
/\[DEF\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/DEF\]/gi
```

You can do also a simple one:

```
/\[DEF\](.*?)\[\/DEF\]/
```

But It will support only 1 occurence, and will not support matching over more than one line.

When I see your tring: `/\[DEF\]([^\[\/DEF]]+)\[\/DEF\]/g` It looks like you don't know what is it mean `.*?`

> The question mark after * makes it ungreedy. If you leave it out, it
> will match everything between the first WORD1 and the last WORD2 where
> if you have multiple occurences of WORD2 the ungreedy operator will
> only match until the first WORD2
> http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/265751-how-does-it-work/

##Example

```js
var source = 'Exampe Source[DEF]my source[/DEF]'
document.write(source + '<br>')
alert('Source: ' + source)
var match = source.match(/\[DEF\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/DEF\]/g)
alert('Match:' + match)
document.write(match + '<br>')
```

Comment: Good. There is just one type of situation when this approach won't work: when there is `[DEF]` and no closing `[/DEF]` with a very long text after `[DEF]` (a timeout will occur). However, I suppose this lazy-dot-matching regex is enough for the current scenario.

Comment: (/\[DEF\]([\s\S]*?)\[/DEF\]/g)      (/\[DEF\](.*?)\[/DEF\]/)    (/\[DEF\](.*?)\[/DEF\]/)  these regex's are invalid when i search multiple record from string. ?  @Amina

Comment: @MJunaidAslam: What language? How are you using the regexps? **Show the code please**.

Comment: Javascript Adding the Code: